# Shoot raycast that overshoot the direction point

Tags: unity-game-engine

What I'm trying to do is overshoot the raycast direction to maximum distance. But it's not detecting a raycast collision even though there's a collision on that direction. Below is my code

```
Ray ray = new Ray(player.position, pointDirection);

if (Physics.Raycast(ray, out hit, Mathf.Infinity))
{
    if (hit.collider != null)
    {
        Debug.Log("hit");
    }
}
```

[image]

Comment: What’s the actual issue? You set the raycast to infinite. Which would be right. But you haven’t said what’s wrong and the picture is only a visual representation.

Comment: @BugFinder sorry I forgot to put my problem. I just Edited it. Thanks

Comment: How are you determining it should have hit something. Remember a raycast is like a micro thin lazer Murphy’s law states if it can miss it will. I had similar with a wall. What it turned out was somehow the texture mattered. Don’t look at me it made no sense. But what do you think it should be hitting? What are the properties on the collider on what you think it should be hitting. Have you considered other raycast options? Is the game 3d or 2d. Could it be above or below the object you thought. Etc

Comment: well I'm making a pool game the object calling the raycast is surrounded by a wall. Let me check about the others that you discussed if it's causing the problem

Comment: @BugFinder but when I use Ray ray = new Ray(player.position, transform.forward) and remove the math.infinity it's working.

Comment: If you put infinity in that ray creation. Not the raycast then it’s probably not pointing at what you thought.